# A matter of logic, intelligence and pacience

Tags: jquery, function, if-statement, logic, submit

I not any good at logic (math for a matter of fact).

I am building a simple function. So I can't figure one problem out.

This function will control two fields in a form, a text input and a select. It's a search form where the search can be performed by a term typed in the text field, or by category selected in the select field and both can be used at same time to reduce/filter results.

[EDITED] The function must control:
- do not allow searches by term, in the text field, with less than 3 characters;
- do not allow empty searches in both fields :);
- allow empty text field (term) with non empty select (category);
- allow non empty text field with empty select.

Then if all is checked the form can be submitted.

[SOLVED]
using this code together with jQuery
vbt is a var to short the text field id, vbf for the form and vslt for the select. smsg is var to the alert error message.
HTML FORM

```
<form method="get" action="search_res.php">
    <label for="q">Search term</label>
    <input type="text" name="q" id="q" />
    <label for="c">Category</label>
    <select name="c" id="c">
        <option value="c1">Cat 1</option>
        <option value="c2">Cat 2</option>
        <option value="c3">Cat 3</option>
        <option value="c4">Cat 4</option>
    </select>
   <button type="submit"><img src="images/submit.png" width="80" height="30" alt="" /></button>
</form>
```

JQUERY CODE

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function submt() {
        if(vbt.val().length >= 3)
            vbf.submit();
        else if((vbt.val() == '') && (vslt.val() != ''))
            vbf.submit();
        else
            alert(smsg);
    }
});
```

Comment: Great! ...and what have you tried?

Comment: Just give us the requirements specification! We'll do your work for you.

Comment: @SimeVidas no you _post_ the code!

Comment: @Raynos Hm, shouldn't the emphasis be on *you*? - "no *you* post the code!" - or is there something wrong with the verb?

Comment: @SimeVidas I was suggesting you _post_ it by mail to him. But I didn't really convey that very well.

Comment: Sorry I had to go away from the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you do...

HTML:

```
<input type="text">

<select>
    <option> All </option>
    <option> Logic </option>
    <option> Intelligence </option>
    <option> Pacience </option>
</select>

<input type="submit" disabled>
```

JavaScript:

```
var text = $('input:text'),
    select = $('select'),
    submit = $('input:submit');

function f() {
    var valid = text[0].value.length >= 3 || select[0].selectedIndex !== 0;
    submit[0].disabled = !valid;
}

text.keyup(f);
select.change(f);
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/DCz9x/1/

Comment: Thanks! I've solved it here, but I will test your code too. Sorry for the long delay.

Comment: I am not using a button type=submit I am using a button type=button, so it calls the function and then submit it. And I don't know if I explained it correctly. My English is not very good.

Comment: @tenshimsm Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/DCz9x/3/

Answer (score 0):

short pseudocode : 
`if(input.strlen<3) input=""`

and

`if( select==empty && input=="" ) return false;`

Comment: i guess youll just wait for copy-paste ready code :P